# Using the summation formula in an inductive proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, formal-proofs

I'm not sure what to do. My instructors feedback is that I cannot use the geometric sum in the proof because I have to use induction. I don't understand this feedback because I don't see how the two are mutually exclusive. I also think that I am using induction. The summation formula for the geometric sum only proves the inductive step and not the original equation. There's also some corrections I need to make to my base case, so please forgive me. But can you all help me with the final inductive step?
[my proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEliz.png)
[instructors feedback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWW2g.png)

Comment: If you assume that you have geometric series results, there is no need to induct.  In your proof, you do not really induct on anything.  So if the assignment was to use induction, I agree with your instructor.

Comment: Please type your question rather than posting links to images since links can get broken and images cannot be searched.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @Randall Oh! I didn't understand I was assuming the conclusion, which means I don't know what an inductive hypothesis is because I thought it was the entire equality both right and left hand side. Thank for! This shows me where my knowledge gap is at and gives me some areas to study.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with your instructor, you cannot use geometric series, because that is effectively what you are trying to prove. The base case looks good. The inductive step would go something like this:

Assume the equation holds for $n=k.$ Then, we have that $$3\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}4^i=4^k-4.$$ Now, take $n=k+1$ on the LHS. We have that $$3\sum_{i=1}^{k}4^i=3\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}4^i+(3\cdot4^k)=4^k-4+(3\cdot4^k)=4\cdot 4^k-4=4^{k+1}-4.$$ Thus, we see that if equality holds for $n=k,$ then equality holds for $n=k+1$ and completed our inductive step. In conjunction with the base case, this completes the proof.

Comment: I see where I was making the mistake. I didn't understand that the proof was only manipulating the sum to equal the right hand side, I thought he hypothesis was the equality all together. Seems pedantic but my mind was sludge and I couldn't see that I was affirming the conclusion. TY for opening the attachments and putting this response together. I should have probably typed everything out.